# How to poll an asynchronous stream and futures generated from stream items in the same loop?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am trying to consume messages coming from a stream, while at the same time processing `async` responses from REST service calls.

I have exemplified the structure of the program with a mock stream and futures:

```rust
use tokio::runtime;

use futures::future;
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

async fn demo() {
    let mut s = stream::repeat::<u32>(9);

    let mut counter = 0;
    while let Some(n) = s.next().await {
        counter += 1;
        if counter % 100 == 0 {
            // simulate a condition that requires sending a msg
            let f = future::ready::<u32>(10);
            // How to poll future 'f' in the same loop as stream 's'?
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let runtime = runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_io()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async move { demo().await });
}
```

How can I poll both the next stream item, or the future output (when a future is available), whichever comes first, in the same loop?

This structure would make it possible for a trading strategy, which sends orders based on a stream of market data items, to listen to the order service results and the market data messages in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

By using the method [`try_flatten()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_flatten) it is possible to turn a stream of streams into a stream. The only catch is that this method is defined on trait: [`TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html) which is a stream of [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) items, and the inner streams must also be of that type.

What it implies is that instead of dealing with type `u32` in my example we are dealing with type `Result<u32, ()>`.

To build a stream out of a future, the [`stream::once()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/fn.once.html) function is used.

To make a stream of streams, as per the `try_flatten()` [method documentation](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#examples-13), a MPSC channel is used.

Here is the complete code of my solution. I have made use of type annotation to better understand what is going on.

```rust
use tokio::runtime;

use futures::future;
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt, TryStreamExt};

use futures::channel::mpsc;

async fn demo() {
    let s: stream::Repeat<Result<u32, ()>> = stream::repeat::<Result<u32, ()>>(Ok(9));
    let (tx, rx): (
        mpsc::UnboundedSender<Result<stream::Once<future::Ready<Result<u32, ()>>>, ()>>,
        mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<Result<stream::Once<future::Ready<Result<u32, ()>>>, ()>>,
    ) = mpsc::unbounded();
    let mut merged = stream::select(s, rx.try_flatten());

    let mut counter: u32 = 0;
    while let Some(n) = merged.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", n);
        counter += 1;
        if counter % 100 == 0 {
            let f: stream::Once<future::Ready<Result<u32, ()>>> =
                stream::once(future::ready::<Result<u32, ()>>(Ok(10)));
            tx.unbounded_send(Ok(f)).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let runtime = runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_io()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async move { demo().await });
}
```

I don't think that using the Tokio runtime makes a difference here, but I might be wrong. Since I am still learning async Rust, any constructive comment or suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.flatten; https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.into_stream; https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/attr.main.html